# Multiple Training Data in Tesseract.js

Tags: javascript, ocr, tesseract

We have created 2 custom .gzip files with trained-data of unique languages / fonts. Need to know how can we invoke the same using Tesseract.recognize function in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Import createWorker function from Tesseract and pass langPath as traineddata.

```
const { createWorker } = Tesseract;
  const worker = createWorker({
    workerPath: 
    langPath: 'traineddata  path here' 
    corePath: 
 });
```